# Word for things that people have different opinions towards

Tags: single-word-requests

This word is a common-ish word, and it has been on my mind all day. It's really frustrating to keep attempting to find out what this word has been alone, so I decided to just ask others here.

The word basically is **directed at things that people have different opinions towards.**

Example: You can't say that art piece is good. Art is _______.

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: What does this word mean? What are you trying to express? What is your question?

Comment: @Rathony I'm trying to figure out what the word is. I've been trying to figure it out all day, all I have is the word meaning.

Comment: The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Rathony Isn't my example of how it is used good?

Comment: You need to edit your question.

Comment: [subjective](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subjective)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please edit the title to be more specific to what you are actually asking about. The first paragraph is all that appears on the front page of the site, and isn't very informative either. What does your word actually **mean**? Have you looked for that meaning in onelook.com's reverse dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the word you are looking for is **subjective**

> sub·jec·tive
>
> 1.
> based on or influenced by personal feelings, tastes, or opinions.

(as defined by google)

Art is subjective, as in, whether it is good or not depends on who is looking at it.

Answer (score -2):

Art is *subjective*.

As for other topics of discussion, possibly "debatable", "controversial", "arguably".

Comment: How does this answer differ from that given 4.5 years ago?